# Adding a custom icon to a selectmenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-selectmenu

I'm working with JQuery & JQuery UI.

I followed the example on the JQuery UI demos for the custom rendering to add icons to the select menu items which is working well. What I'm having trouble with is adding the selected icon to the button that the user clicks to show the menu. I followed the accepted answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27817806/keep-picture-with-selectmenu-of-jquery-ui?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), and I've got an icon showing, but it doesn't show the custom icon I want it to, it shows one of the standard icons. I've tried many different variations for the CSS and adding classes to the span for the icon, but I can't get it right. When I inspect the element in Chrome, it always shows the image as being derived from the 'ui-button ui-icon' class, not my custom icon class. What combination of CSS and classes to I need to make it show correctly?

I've got a selectmenu defined as follows:

```
<select name="sourceIcon" id="jsSourceIconSelect">
     <option value="AM-FM-2" data-class="am-fm">AM-FM</option>
     <option value="CD-2" data-class="cd">CD</option>
     <option value="Climate-2" data-class="climate">Climate</option>
     <option value="Display-Alt-2" data-class="display-alt">Display Alt</option>
     <option value="Display-2" data-class="display">Display</option>
     <option value="DVR-2" data-class="dvr">DVR</option>
     <option value="Energy Management-2" data-class="energy-management">Energy Management</option>
     <option value="Favorites-2" data-class="favorites">Favorites</option>
     <option value="Film Reel-2" data-class="film-reel">Film Reel</option>
     <option value="Home-2" data-class="home">Home</option>
</select>
```

and the associated javascript:

```
$.widget("custom.iconselectmenu", $.ui.selectmenu, {
            _renderItem: function(ul, item) {
                var li = $("<li>"),
                wrapper = $("<div>",{text: item.label});

                if(item.disabled){
                    li.addClass("ui-state-disabled");
                }

                $("<span>",  {
                    style: item.element.attr("data-style"),
                    "class":"ui-icon " + item.element.attr("data-class")
                }).appendTo(wrapper);

                return li.append(wrapper).appendTo(ul);
            }
        });

        $("#jsSourceIconSelect").iconselectmenu({
            select: function(event, ui){
                $("#" + this.id + "ImgSelected").attr("class","ui-icon" + ui.item.element.data("class"));
            },
            create: function(event, ui){
                var widget=$(this).iconselectmenu("widget");
                $span = $('<span id="' + this.id + 'ImgSelected" class="ui-icon ' + $(this).children(":first").data("class") +'">').appendTo(widget);
            }
        })
        .iconselectmenu("menuWidget")
            .addClass("ui-menu-icons customicons");
```

and the associated css:

```
.ui-selectmenu-menu .ui-menu.customicons .ui-menu-item-wrapper{
        padding: .5em 0 .5em 3em;
    }

    .ui-selectmenu-menu .ui-menu.customicons .ui-menu-item .ui-icon{
        background-image: url("ui-icons-largeicons.png");
        height: 32px;
        width: 32px;
        top: .1em;
    }
```

edit: thought I should add the css for a few of the icons:

```
.ui-icon.am-fm{ background-position: 0 0; }
.ui-icon.cd{ background-position: -32px 0; }
.ui-icon.climate{ background-position: -64px 0; }
.ui-icon.display-alt{ background-position: -96px 0;}
.ui-icon.display{ background-position: -128px 0;}
.ui-icon.dvr{background-position: -160px 0;}
.ui-icon.energy-management{ background-position: -192px 0;}
.ui-icon.favorites{background-position: -224px 0;}
.ui-icon.film-reel{background-position: -256px 0;}
.ui-icon.home{background-position: -288px 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I handled a custom icon in selectmenu is to change position-x, position-y to normal settings because that was the reason the image wasn't shown.
I just made the following css :

```
.ui-icon {
        background-image: url("/Images/dropdown-icon_2018-10-03/dropdown-icon.png");
        background-position-x: 0;
        background-position-y: 5px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using selectmenu examples as OP i came up with the following solution:

```
$(function () {
    $.widget("custom.iconselectmenu", $.ui.selectmenu, {
        _renderItem: function (ul, item) {
            var li = $("<li>"),
                wrapper = $("<div>", { html: item.element.html() });

            if (item.disabled) {
                li.addClass("ui-state-disabled");
            }

            $("<span>", {
                style: item.element.attr("data-style"),
                "class": "ui-icon " + item.element.attr("data-class")
            })
                .appendTo(wrapper);

            return li.append(wrapper).appendTo(ul);
        }
    });

    $("#people")
        .iconselectmenu({
            create: function (event, ui) {
                var widget = $(this).iconselectmenu("widget");
                $span = $('<span id="' + this.id + 'selected" class="avatar-selected"> ').html("&nbsp;").appendTo(widget);
                $span.attr("style", $(this).children(":first").data("style"));
            },
            change: function (event, ui) {
                $("#" + this.id + 'selected').attr("style", ui.item.element.data("style"));
            }
        })
        .iconselectmenu("menuWidget")
        .addClass("ui-menu-icons avatar");
});
```

and corresponding CSS:

```
    .ui-selectmenu-menu .ui-menu.avatar .ui-menu-item-wrapper {
        padding: 2px 10px 0 30px;
    }

    .ui-selectmenu-menu .ui-menu.avatar .ui-menu-item .ui-icon {
        height: 24px;
        width: 24px;
        top: 0.1em;
    }

    .ui-selectmenu-text {
        padding-left: 2em;
    }

    .avatar-selected {
        position:absolute;
        height: 24px;
        width: 24px;
        right:auto;
        margin-top:-12px;
        top:50%;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
    }
```