# How to use colored circles in ASP Dropdownlist ListItems? (without jQuery)

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, drop-down-menu

**Goal**: I would like to have a Dropdown list that shows the color green if someones if Availability is True, and red is someones Availability is False.

NOTE: I need to do it without jQuery (I was just told we are not allowed to use jquery in our project).

**Problem/Background**:
The only way I could get anything to show was with CSS and placing it on the Dropdown list itself, as seen in the first row of this image for Prof Smith. You'll see the next row with Prof. Jones is displaying the actual boolean value from the database in the dropdown, although I want a colored circle.

I'd like it to be within the dropdown box itself. It should also (eventually) be able to update the value in the DB if they make a change.

How can I get these circles to show inside the dropdown box?

What I want it the dropdown to look like:

[image: Desired dropdown]

What it actually looks like:

[image: Availability image]

**What I've done:**

- Tried CSS on the DropdownList as well as the ListItem, and inside of the listitem.
- I have also tried SVG but that didn't insert into the ListItem at all
- I've tried adding CSS through the C# code but couldn't get it to work that way

**CSS**:

```
.dot {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.greendot {
    background-color: #89C742;
}

.reddot {
    background-color: #fe0505;
}
```

**aspx/html**:

```
<asp:DropdownList runat="server" id="ddl1" class="dot greendot">
    <asp:ListItem ID="LT1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem ID="RT1"></asp:ListItem>              
</asp:DropdownList>

<asp:DropdownList runat="server" id="ddl2">
    <asp:ListItem ID="LT2"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropdownList>
```

**C#**:

```
LT2.Text = professorStatsList[1].Available.ToString();
```

Comment: Pretty sure this has been tried before and the only way is with a javascript library. Maybe.

Comment: @angleUr below is my answer you can check and possibly gice it a green tick and an upvote

Comment: @nikhilsugandh hi, thank you, it looks like your solution uses/references jQuery. I need one that does not use jquery.

Comment: @angleUr no I have used javascriot no jQuery!!

Comment: @nikhilsugandh can I remove your reference then? You have: <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can create rounded `option` element without creating a complete copy of the DDL with `div` elements like in [this example](https://andrejgajdos.com/custom-select-dropdown/). But the closest you can get is something like this.

Give the DDL a class, in this case `RoundedDDL`

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" CssClass="RoundedDDL">
    <asp:ListItem Text="" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="" Value="True"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="" Value="False"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Then with CSS make it round and remove the arrow with `appearance: none;`. You can style the `select` elements by value with `option[value="True"]`

```
<style>
    .RoundedDDL {
        appearance: none;
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        border-radius: 15px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        background-color: white;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    select option {
        background-color: white;
    }

    select option[value="True"] {
       background-color: green;
    }

    select option[value="False"] {
        background-color: red;
    }

    .red {
        background-color: red;
    }

    .green {
        background-color: green;
    }
</style>
```

And then some javascript to add the correct class to the DDL when a specific value has been selected.

```
<script>
    $('.RoundedDDL').bind('change', function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.removeClass('green');
        $this.removeClass('red');

        if ($this.val() === 'True') {
            $this.addClass('green');
        } else if ($this.val() === 'False') {
            $this.addClass('red');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi @VDWWD, I implemented this, and it makes the dropdown itself a circle, then changes back to a square when I click on it with red filling the entire background. I want it to be a square, but have the values inside show circles. I added an image to my original post to clarify. Please let me know if this can be achieved with your code.

Comment: No it's not possible unfortunately. Because with CSS you can only do so much with an `<option>`, like color or background color. border-radius is not supported. If you absolutely want it you need something like the solution of @nikhil sugandh

Comment: Hi VDWWD, unfortunately his solution uses bootstrap which has list items under a header. I want it to show a default value based on what is in the database. I want it to look similar to Julian's solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would just create some images and implement these CSS classes:

```
.available {
    background-image:url('images/available.png');
}

.unavailable {
    background-image:url('images/unavailable.png');
}
```

and would make sure that the items have the class you expect (set the `CssClass` attribute)

Also, you may want to implement a new `Control` class which extends `ListItem`, has a logical value for available and in the correct event (maybe `PreRender`, but I'm not sure) you set the `CssClass` to the correct value. That would separate your concerns.

Comment: thanks. The image URL location changes depending on the server (REL/PROD), so I have it set in the C#. I tried using C# to add it but, if I add it to the ListItem it errors with "ListItem does not contain a definition for Style ..." -- how can I set it equal to the variable professorAvatar ?

Comment: I also tried : ListItem item = ddlAvailability1.Items[0];
item.Attributes["style"] = "background: url(" + professorAvatar + ");background-repeat:no-repeat;";

Comment: @angleUr maybe this link helps you clarify how you can style elements via C#: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104458/applying-styles-to-listitems-in-checkboxlist

Comment: I tried that as well, but nothing shows, its just an empty box.

Comment: @angleUr can you show the code you have used to do so?

Comment: I have since deleted, but I did a number of variations from that link. I believe one of them was: 
ListItem item = ddlAvailability1.Items[0];
item.Attributes.Add("Style", "background: url(" + professorAvatar + ");background-repeat:no-repeat;";
I also tried creating ListItem in C# and adding it to the ddlAvailability1 in C# 
I've tried Style lowercase and uppercase
It always just shows an empty DropdownList

Comment: @angleUr you might be doing it in the wrong event/method. The point is that this should work. If it is not working for you, then something is wrong. You need to specify ```runat="server"``` in your markup for your tag. I believe ```Page_Load``` is an event that you could implement this into, but you might want prerender instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I misunderstood your question, but I understand that you want to put the circle inside each **ListItem**.

One way to do this is to use a customizable selectmenu using [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#custom_render), but if you want to keep the circle in the **selected item** you will have to make a small change, for this I have used the answer to this question as a base: [Keep picture with Selectmenu of jQuery UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27817806/keep-picture-with-selectmenu-of-jquery-ui/60000960#60000960)

**ASPX/JS/CSS Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>

        $(function () {
            $.widget("custom.iconselectmenu", $.ui.selectmenu, {
                _renderItem: function (ul, item) {
                    var li = $("<li>"),
                        wrapper = $("<div>", { html: item.element.html() });

                    if (item.disabled) {
                        li.addClass("ui-state-disabled");
                    }

                    $("<span>", {
                        style: item.element.attr("data-style"),
                        "class": "ui-icon " + item.element.attr("data-class")
                    })
                        .appendTo(wrapper);

                    return li.append(wrapper).appendTo(ul);
                }
            });

            $("#<%=dpwTest.ClientID%>")
                .iconselectmenu({
                    create: function (event, ui) {
                        var widget = $(this).iconselectmenu("widget");
                        $span = $('<span id="' + this.id + 'selected" class="status-selected"> ').html("&nbsp;").appendTo(widget);
                        // Keep always the selected item class (for example, when the page load a specific item)
                        $span.attr("style", $(this).children(":selected").data("style"));
                    },
                    change: function (event, ui) {
                        $("#" + this.id + 'selected').attr("style", ui.item.element.data("style"));
                    }
                })
                .iconselectmenu("menuWidget")
                .addClass("ui-menu-icons status");
        });

    </script>

    <style>

        .ui-selectmenu-menu .ui-menu.status .ui-menu-item-wrapper {
            padding: 15px 10px 0 30px;
            padding-bottom: 10px;
        }

        .ui-selectmenu-menu .ui-menu.status .ui-menu-item .ui-icon {
            height: 24px;
            width: 24px;
            top: 0.1em;
        }

        .ui-selectmenu-text {
            padding-left: 2em;
        }

        .status-selected {
            position:absolute;
            right:auto;
            margin-top:-12px;
            top:50%;
        }

        .ui-icon, .ui-widget-content .ui-icon {
            background-image: none;
        }

        .ui-selectmenu-button.ui-button {
            text-align: left;
            white-space: nowrap;
            width: 7em;
        }

    </style>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <label for="dpwTest">Prof. Smith</label>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="dpwTest" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="True" data-class="status" data-style="height: 25px; width: 25px; background-color: green;border-radius: 50%; display: inline-block;" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="False" data-class="status" data-style="height: 25px; width: 25px; background-color: red;border-radius: 50%; display: inline-block;" />
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: I like the look of this! But can this be done with just C#/ASP.net and no jQuery ?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not really sure how to apply it in Vanille JS, it is possible, but in my case, it would take me a while to do it...

Comment: I tried this out. The only thing that is different is, I put the css into a css file I already have. I added the jquery to some js I already have in the aspx file. It says Yes and No in the dropdown, but it doesn't show the circles

Comment: And in the css file do you have other styles than what I put in my answer? Maybe there may be a conflict between styles

Comment: Yes, but none of them start with ".ui-"

Comment: I see you have 3 jquery URLs, do I need all 3? I currently am using: <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"

Comment: Yes, you need all 3, you need the other two: `jquery-ui.js` and `jquery-ui.css`, jQuery UI is a different library than jQuery

Comment: When I add these references, instead of showing the circles, for some reason it shows "^." in the dropdown

Comment: check the order of the js libraries (it is important), also look in the console if there may be any errors

Comment: The only error was:  HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier). 
GET - http://localhost:53595/resources/demos/style.css -- I already have a reference to css though <link href="Content/myfile.css" rel="stylesheet" />

Answer (score 0):

This is it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <meta name="Description" content="Enter your description here" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.0/css/all.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css" />
    <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Dropdown
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">person1&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">person2</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">person3</a>
                    </div>
                </li>

            </ul>

        </div>
    </nav>
    <Script>
        var avaliability = [true, false, false];
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-item');

        for (var i = x.length; i--;) {
            if (avaliability[i] === true) {
                x[i].innerHTML = `person&nbsp&nbsp<span class="badge badge-success"
                style="border-radius: 100%;">&nbsp&nbsp</span>`

            } else {
                x[i].innerHTML = `person&nbsp&nbsp<span class="badge badge-danger"
                style="border-radius: 100%;">&nbsp&nbsp</span>`;

            }
        }
    </Script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.1/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

check
https://jsfiddle.net/yubeog4c/

just get the values into availability array and it should converted to boolean types.

Thanks!!!!

Comment: hi @nikhill, I like how the circles look, but the dropdown itself looks very different from the dropdown I had. It should show whatever the current value is without having to click the down arrow. The down arrow should be when you want to change. Also I see you got rid of the .net DropdownList and ListItems.

Comment: @angleUr as with your requirement when clicking dropdown the values should change ,i guess you should have to use jquery with it.!!

Comment: @angleUr I have used simply used Bootstrap

Comment: They dont change when clicking the dropdown, the dropdown should already have both values, but defaults to whatever the value in the DB is. It should look like the solution Julian has(but his uses jquery so I cant implement it).